# executing code with capistrano regardless of errors

Tags: deployment, capistrano, continuous-deployment

I'm looking for a way to make sure capistrano will start my tomcat at the end of the run, no matter what. 
I stop it at the beginning of the deployment run, but in the unlikely case of an error thereafter, I cannot start it again, even if the error were only that the artifact I want to deploy wasn't found.
I could add starting it to every on_rollback{} there is, but I'd rather find a cleaner way.

So, in other words, is there a capistrano equivalent to Java's **finally** keyword?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking about Capistrano 2.

There are before and after commands.

You could do:

```
 after :deploy, :restart_tomcat
```

There are also ways to do on_error => continue

Here are some snippets from a my restart scripts for a java application. Notice the placement of before (or after) is before any namespace declarations. Also note that in stopping the app, I am ignoring errors. I want errors if the app fails to start.

Keep in mind here I call initialize on an environment deploy, or the task can be called manually by a developer to reset an environment. It works whether called in :deploy or as app.deploy.initialize_app

```
before "app:deploy:initialize_app", "app:deploy:stop_app"

namespace :app do
 namespace :deploy do

  task :initialize_app, :roles => :app do
  #Do Stuff.
  end

  task :stop_app, :roles => :app, :on_error => :continue do
  run "cd '#{deploy_to}/current/app/bin'; #{java_home_cmd}; ./tcserver.sh #{stage_name} stop"
end

  task :restart_app, :roles => :app do
  app.deploy.stop_app
  print "Sleeping 60 seconds.\n"
  sleep 60
  run "cd '#{deploy_to}/current/app/bin'; #{java_home_cmd}; ./tcserver.sh #{stage_name} start"
end
end
end
```

Comment: +1 for the helpful piece of advice about on_error there, but unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem. I don't want to ignore errors in my tasks, I want to have some task that will be executed regardless of whether errors occured or not.

Comment: Consider overriding rollback itself

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been quite a while, but since others may happen to find this question i'll leave here the piece of code that solved my problem.

You could wrap your task in a Ruby **(begin | rescue | ensure | end)** block. As you can see below:

```rb
task(:my_task) do
  begin
    run "echo 'execute my deploy'; false"
  rescue
    run "echo 'executed on error'"
  ensure
    run "echo 'executed no matter what'"
  end
end
```

You can append **true** or **false** at the end of the execution (as on line 3, above) to test the failure or success of a command.

Comment: It works nicely. I'm using something very similar to the code above in a couple of my own deploy recipes. Unfortunately, i haven't got time to test it on capistrano 3+ (since it changes a lot of things). But i believe it should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer again with another technique, since adding a comment to the previous answer is too short.

In one of my projects, I override rollback itself:

```
namespace :deploy do
 namespace :rollback do

  task :default do
   liquibase.deploy.rollback_liquibase
   revision
   cleanup
  end
 end
end
```

you could also try hooking rollback:revision itself:

before "deploy:rollback:revision", "app:do_task"